# phpmyadmin, neginx error.log - Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin, open-basedir

I have this message on phpmyadmin website

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

On the 'click here' page I have this: 
[Page printscreen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhh4vxs6e1cq0o7/1.png)

My nginx error are:

```
    2014/06/27 15:08:15 [error] 4922#0: *886 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
    PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.2014/06/27 15:17:07 [error] 5119#0: *939 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
    PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions" while reading response header from upstream, client: 1***, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/js/messages.php?lang=en&db=&token=**** HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock:", host: "****:8080", referrer: "https://****:8080/phpmyadmin/chk_rel.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=****"
```

I give them permissions with this cmd for all 3 files:

```
chgrp www-data  /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php
chmod 644 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php
```

How to fix the open_basedir restrictions?

I checked Google but didn't find anything. Please give me some help or tips how to fix it. Thank you!

Ubuntu version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04

Comment: are you sure you have installed everything that you need? I mean full lamp and `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

Comment: I have ispconfig 3 installed, wordpress runing good, something from vhost config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my configuration:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 feb 14 10:05 phpmyadmin/
```

that's for folder. And for those two files:

```
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data   60 feb 14 10:05 blowfish_secret.inc.php
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data    0 feb 14 10:05 config.inc.php
```

Hope this will help. Also check for php5-mcrypt extension. If it's not working properly, use

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

to install it, and then just restart ngnix. here are commands:

```
chmod 755 /var/lib/phpmyadmin
chmod 664 /var/lib/blowfish_secret.inc.php
chmod 664 /var/lib/config.inc.php
```

those commands should work. :)

Comment: Sorry restart Nginx, not apache :)

Comment: If that don't help check this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin#Nginx

Comment: no, those are not commands, those are my permissions... for mcrypt
http://askubuntu.com/questions/360646/cant-use-php-extension-mcrypt-in-ubuntu-13-10-nginx-php-fpm but pay attention on `config.d` folder it's changed on 14.04

Comment: can u give me cmd please for permission?

Comment: The problem was fixed, but i dont know how and when. I forget that I need to log-out so that config take effect. 10x for help bro!

Comment: The permissions shown above by MrCkobe on "blowfish_secret_.inc.php" and "config.inc.php" are 640, yet he specifies chmod 664, which is obviously not the same.