# phpmyadmin complains about permissions and open_basedir - but they all appear correct

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, php, open-basedir, ubuntu-14.10

phpmyadmin has been installed and working fine for months, installed via this repo:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxpoldo/phpmyadmin/ubuntu utopic main`

Suddenly, I couldn't login; no in-page errors but the logs showed:

```
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions"
PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions"
```

So, I checked:

```
ll /etc/phpmyadmin

drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data  4096 Nov 16 20:11 ./
drwxr-xr-x 132 root     root     12288 Nov 17 15:33 ../
-rw-r-----   1 www-data www-data   549 Nov 16 20:11 config-db.php
```

and

```
ll /var/lib/phpmyadmin

drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Oct  8 15:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 62 root     root     4096 Nov 12 13:10 ../
-rw-r-----  1 www-data www-data 4478 Nov 16 19:48 config.inc.php
```

I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453013/401713) and changed the user and group permissions to match the example (user:root, group:www-data) and changed the directory permissions to match.

I double, triple checked that no open-basedir restrictions are in effect, and I checked phpinfo()
I tried changing the permissions to be that of the fpm worker pool.
I rebooted.
I did an `sudo apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin`.

The ONLY thing I've done inbetween is to follow [this guide to installing freePBX](http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/HTGS/Installing+FreePBX+12+on+Ubuntu+Server+14.10#InstallingFreePBX12onUbuntuServer14.10-UpdateYourSystem), and 90% of what it wanted was on my machine anyway; only things like sqlite were installed, and I can't even be sure it was that which stopped it working. Long shot, but perhaps worth mentioning.

Everything else, all other sites etc, are running fine. Before I lose any more hair than I have done in the last 5 hours, I'd really appreciate some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: do you read my answer ?

Comment: Hi Mike. Yes, I did, and I commented on it back in 2016. Also, the answer wasn't really applicable to my situation, as my question was tagged with nginx, your answer applied to Apache, and I had resolved it nearly 2 years previously in my answer.
But I am sure the answer will indeed be of some use to others using Apache. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a rather misleading message from phpmyadmin:

```
Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.
```

But anyone running multiple sites, using php-fpm and concerned at all about security will have separate pools for each site.

The solution, in my particular case was:

```
chown -R phpma:phpma /var/lib/phpmyadmin
chown -R phpma:phpma /etc/phpmyadmin
chown -R phpma:phpma /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`

Incidentally, it appears that doing a package install on Ubuntu splatters files all over the place, and it goes a little something like this:

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

includes the following files in this order, which really won't need touching unless you want to up the login cookie validity.

```
/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php // self explanatory
/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php // LoginCookieValidity etc
/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php // Leave this one alone
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php // auth, host, connection etc
```

I hope this helps someone else at any rate.

Comment: I resolved this similar issue by adding the relevant user to the www-data group leaving the original permissions untouched. sudo usermod -a -G www-data phpma

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly due to the fact you are using mpm_itk_module.

If yes, you have to use in your apache settings :

```
<ifmodule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId myuser www-data
</ifmodule>
```

instead:

```
<ifmodule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId myuser myuser
</ifmodule>
```

phpmyadmin need group www-data, and if you use AssignUserId, with another group it fails off course.

And you can add to you apache config in "Directory":

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/yourpath/htmldir:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin"
```

Replace /home/yourpath/htmldir by your own web dir.

I hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just to say in the end I gave up and now use adminer. MUCH better! One file, no hassle.